# 3ds Max - maxscript button RENDERABLE properties switch on/off problem

Tags: max, 3dsmax, maxscript, 3ds

I want to know how can a setup a button for switch the renderable properties beetwen on and off.

Using the maxscript listener I can do one or another, but I can't make a script that change beetwen them

```
$.renderable = off
$.renderable = on
```

And this also works:

```
if $.renderable = on then $.renderable = off
```

But I don't understand why the opposite doesn't:

```
if $.renderable = off then $.renderable = on
```

I also tried this but no luck either.

```
if $.renderable = on then  $.renderable = off 
else $.renderable = on
```

Answer (score 2):

'=' is assignment, that's why your second example doesn't work, for comparison you'd use '==' instead. If you have a single object selected, the easiest way to toggle the state is

```
$.renderable = not $.renderable
```